# Uploading Big MySql Files in Phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, php-ini

Im trying to upload a 3.8gb sql dump into phpmyadmin, in wamp. I set the max_file sizes among other things to 5gb and even restarted the server multiple times. The php_info(); also gives me 5gb as the file size.
I would like to break the file into smaller chunks so that I can upload it bit by bit,if the entire thing isnt possible, and have looked for such tools. Used one though http://www.rusiczki.net/2007/01/24/sql-dump-file-splitter/ but it gives me an error at 2gb.
Could anyone suggest anything that i could do to get my dump into mysql?

Thanks a lot

Comment: If it is only the one file, why not just do it by eye? About 500mb worth of queries at a time making sure not to cut any insert/create/transactions in half.

Comment: But, when i open it in notepad or any other text editor, it says the file is too big to be opened. I would love to do it at 500mb at a time, but i cant seem to get it cut down/ opened up to be cut down to that size.

Comment: I used the 010Editor and opened the file. Thus i decreased the file size. The data itself was about 3gb(woah!), how ever even after opening it in the editor i noticed special characters like  Ã and so on.. By looking on here..i found its an encoding error.  Now i would like to know if i change the encoding format, will the current data be altered or just the new incoming data.

Answer (score 2):

Traverse to your mysql bin directory (e.g. below)

```
D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql15.1.36\bin>
```

Then you can import any large database from your dump file giving the following command (e.g. below)

```
mysql -u username -ppassword database_name < dump.sql
```

Comment: I used Commandprompt to traverse to it and executed mysqldump application. However when the above query is run, it comes back as the query written above is incorrect.

Comment: What error message do you get? I believe the host is missing from this very good answer.

Comment: yup the host was missing. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should really skip phpmyadmin and do it through the command line. The correct command is:

```
    $ mysql -u username -p -h localhost DATA-BASE-NAME < data.sql
```

If you are still unsure about that one (although try it, you'll be surprised how easy it is) you can have a go at mysql workbench.

Comment: I tried it with mysql workbench, but ran into an unforeseen problem: there are special characters in the data. I think its either database corruption or just an encoding problem. But how do i fix it for the current data is what im wondering now.